# Table cell alignment not working

Tags: c#, alignment, tablecell

I have a table which has a label in the 1st row and a `DateTimePicker` in the 2nd row as follows:

```
Table _Table = new Table();

TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
TableRow row2 = new TableRow();
this._Table.Rows.Add(row1);
this._Table.Rows.Add(row2);

TableCell dateCell = new TableCell();
TableCell labelCell = new TableCell();

labelCell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Bottom;
labelCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
dateCell.Controls.Add(_DtProposalSigned);
labelCell.Controls.Add(savedLabel);
row1.Cells.Add(labelCell);
row2.Cells.Add(dateCell);
```

I am trying to align the label cell so that label is to the right, above the `DateTimePicker`, but I get the result as follows (`Label` in the center), though I have aligned it to the right!

[image]

Comment: Please always include the platform you are using as a Tag!

Comment: Where is savedLabel defined??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the same code and it's working perfect for me. So, here is a check list you may give a try.

- Make sure that you haven't mentioned `width` anywhere for 'savedLabel' or `Text/innerHTML` of `savedLabel`
- Make sure that you haven't provided value to the `width` property of `labelCell`
- Make sure that there are no blank spaces after 'Saved !'
- If you are assigning dynamic value to `savedLabel` like `<div>Saved<div>` then make sure that you haven't given it a fixed width like `<div style='width:100px;'>Saved</div>`
- You can check all these and other attributes by right clicking on the `Saved!` and then selecting `Inspect Element`. Examine the `<span></span>` element rendered for the label and I am sure, you will be able to find the exact issue and hence the solution.

In case these are not helpful, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks. I had an innerHTML which was causing this!